# Sandbox blocking firebase macOS Monterey Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using firebase realtime database as my backend in my IOS app. The app is working great on my older MacBook Pro 2014 (macOS Big Sur), when the app loads I am able to fetch data from firebase. But I am unable to fetch data from firebase on the new 2021 MacBook Pro 16 inches running (macOS Monterey). The app loads, but unable to fetch data from firebase, I am getting error: **[Sandbox] Could not enable Mach bootstrap, errno = 22**. I am using the latest version of firebase SDK, Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try switching to SPM if you are using cocoapods

Comment: I was using SPM and switched to Cocoa-pods and got the same error. I also create a new app in firebase and import it in my app and the same error.

Comment: What version of Cocoapods are you using and can we see your podfile (probably unrelated but will add clarity)